# How can I integrate end-to-end tracing in Kibana?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, open-telemetry

I want to add end-to-end tracing to my application and see that the Kibana dashboard provides a nice interface to visualize this data.

**My issue: As far as I can tell viewing Elastic App search request is only built in but what if I want metrics for any request for my app, how can I integrate this?**

The data I am mostly interested would be things like status codes returned at each step and how long it takes. I have done some research and found **openTelemetry** to be widely used for end-to-end tracing but I am unsure if it can be used in Kibana dashboard somehow.

Comment: Yes it can. You need to use OpenTelemetry Collector and send the traces to Elastic using the Elastic exporter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step in this is to use the [Elastic exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/elasticsearchexporter). This will ensure that the Metrics/Traces/Logs get exported to ES indices.

What you mention here is a classic case of TraceUI where you can look at dependencies between services, the timeline etc. This can be visualized with [Jaeger UI](https://logz.io/blog/jaeger-and-the-elk-stack/)